# variable scope migrating from php5/smarty2.6 to php7/smarty3.1

Tags: php-7, smarty3

I'm currently trying to upgrade a few of our sites that were in PHP5 and Smarty 2.6 to PHP7 and Smarty 3.1.31.

We previously had a site with a system of classes extending other classes, here is a simplified version of it:

```
class Site extends WebView
{
    //functions
}

class WebView extends LandingPage
{
    //functions
}

class LandingPage extends Smarty
{
    function LandingPage()
    {
        $this->sessionInit = false;

        $this->flag = array();
        $this->engineVersion = '';

        $this->charset = 'utf-8';
        $this->content_type = 'text/html';
        $this->strings = array();
        $this->rtid=null;
    }
}
```

and before, this worked fine in that all of the variables were correctly site using `$this->variable_name`. i oculd access them directly using $this, such as `$this->flag['TEST']` from inside classes, or externally i could use  `$site`, such as `$site->flag['TEST']`. Now however I am getting a series of undefined property errors

```
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$sessionInit in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$flag in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$engineVersion in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$charset in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$content_type in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$strings in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$rtid in /var/www/html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php on line 1447
```

I went into the Smarty class (obviously I didn't write this) and grabbed out the function for line 1447, which is the generic setter:

```
/**
* <<magic>> Generic setter.
* Calls the appropriate setter function.
* Issues an E_USER_NOTICE if no valid setter is found.
*
* @param string $name  property name
* @param mixed  $value parameter passed to setter
*/
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    if (isset($this->accessMap[ $name ])) {
        $method = 'set' . $this->accessMap[ $name ];
        $this->{$method}($value);
    } elseif (in_array($name, $this->obsoleteProperties)) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (is_object($value) && method_exists($value, $name)) {
            $this->$name = $value;
        } else {
            trigger_error('Undefined property: ' . get_class($this) . '::$' . $name, E_USER_NOTICE);
        }
    }
}
```

it's generic, and used everywhere, so i would assume that is fine and the issue is how i am calling it. what's getting me is how the errors refer to `Site::$sessionInit`, as if the variable had to be site in the Site, and is getting mad when i try and set it in the landingpage.

i know that variable scope has changed some in php7, is this telling me i need setters for all my variables in the site class? would i have to do one for each variable or would a generic work? (it seems like smarty already has a generic that is not working)

Comment: How is the class used with Smarty? What functions do you call from the Smarty library and how?

Answer (score 0):

```
Notice: Undefined property: Site::$sessionInit in /var/www/html/vendor ....
....
....
```

this kind of error doesn't means that the variables is called from out of it's scopes.

this is mean that you are trying to call a variable which is not defined anywhere before.

and to solve this , you simply need to define those variables as follows:

```
class LandingPage extends Smarty
{
    public $sessionInit;
    public $flag; // or what ever the right visibility term
    // .... and so on
    function LandingPage()
    {
        $this->sessionInit = false;

        $this->flag = array();
        $this->engineVersion = '';

        $this->charset = 'utf-8';
        $this->content_type = 'text/html';
        $this->strings = array();
        $this->rtid=null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'll try this out. is this just a function of php5 being very forgiving and declaring the variables on our applications behalf if it hasn't found them before, whereas php7 wants the app to be very explicit?

Comment: i don't think so, you may hide up this notices by setting `display_errors` to no in php.ini file